# How to remove commented properties from properties file using ant build?

Tags: java, ant, properties-file

I want to remove commented properties from properties file through ant build. For security purpose, I don't want to expose my production properties on sandbox servers.

Properties file:

```
#production properties
#redis.master.url=redis.prod.master.compny.com
#redis.slave.url=redis.prod.slave.compny.com

#sandboxproperties
redis.master.url=redis.sandbox.master.compny.com
redis.slave.url=redis.sandbox.slave.compny.com
```

so, my war package should have following properties file:

```
redis.master.url=redis.sandbox.master.compny.com
redis.slave.url=redis.sandbox.slave.compny.com
```

Comment: There are better ways to do this.  I would make two property files, and have different Ant targets like `<target name="sandbox">` and `<target name="production">`, which each copy the desired property file into the build under the name expected by the application.

Comment: sounds good; so the production properties would not be packaged in the archive if set the target to `sandbox` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html):

> Apache Ant provides an optional task for editing property files. This is very useful when wanting to make unattended modifications to configuration files for application servers and applications. Currently, the task maintains a working property file with the ability to add properties or make changes to existing ones. **Since Ant 1.8.0 comments and layout of the original properties file are preserved.**

So depending on which version of ant build you are using you may be able to remove comments from properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a script in ant:

```
<macrodef name="remove-properties-comments">
    <attribute name="inFile" />
    <attribute name="outFile" />
    <sequential>
        <script language="javascript">
            <![CDATA[
                // get the arguments
                var inFile = "@{inFile}"
                var outFile = "@{outFile}"

                // or get properties from the ant environment
                // eg: <property name="property.from.ant.project" value="value" />
                // var antProp = project.getProperty("property.from.ant.project");

                // load Java types
                var File = Java.type("java.io.File")
                var PrintWriter = Java.type("java.io.PrintWriter")
                var Scanner = Java.type("java.util.Scanner")

                // init reader and writer
                var reader = new Scanner(new File(inFile))
                var writer = new PrintWriter(outFile)

                // if previous line ended in '\' then it is a muliline property
                // so the following line should always be included
                var multiline = false
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    var line = reader.nextLine();
                    // you could exclude blank lines too if you want
                    if (multiline || !(line.startsWith("#") || line.startsWith("!"))) {
                        writer.println(line);
                    }
                    multiline = line.endsWith("\\");
                }
               ]]>
        </script>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="test">
    <remove-properties-comments inFile="path/to/inFile.properties" outFile="path/to/outFile.properties" />
</target>
```

Comment: thanks xtratic, I found a way(posted my answer) that will work for every file in the provided directory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out simply by using `replaceregexp`.

```
<target>
    <replaceregexp match="\n#(.*)" replace="" flags="g" byline="false">
        <fileset dir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes" includes="**/*.properties" />
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

Here `\n#(.*)` matches the `<newline>`(`\n`) followed by `#` followed by any set of characters(`*`).